# Determine when all files have uploaded successfully in dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, file-upload, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone.js to upload to my website. The uploader is in a modal, which I want to automatically close when all files have been uploaded successfully.

To do this I am using the following code:

```
buttonUpload.on("complete", function (file) {

    var remaining = buttonUpload.getRejectedFiles().length + buttonUpload.getQueuedFiles().length + buttonUpload.getUploadingFiles().length

    if (remaining == 0) {
        $("#modal-upload-file").modal('hide');
    }
});
```

I would expect this code to add together the number of files that have failed, have not yet uploaded and are uploading. If this is zero, then the  modal closes.

I was able to determine that `buttonUpload.getRejectedFiles()` does not include files that received an error when uploading. From reading the documentation, I can see no way of checking if every file has uploaded successfully like I want to. How can I do this?

Comment: There is an event you can listen for: http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-queuecomplete

Comment: @a.j. This fires when an attempt has been made for every file, even if the server responded with a bad http status for some of them.

Comment: what if you count the erroneous files in the on complete handler and then on event-queuecomplete, check if that count is > 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution.

On success, the file is removed from the queue:

```
buttonUpload.on("success", function(file) {
    buttonUpload.removeFile(file);
});
```

Then, when the queue is completed, if any files remain they were not successful.

```
buttonUpload.on("queuecomplete", function (file) {
    if (buttonUpload.getAcceptedFiles().length > 0) {
        $("#file-error-warning").slideDown();
    } else {
        $("#modal-upload-file").modal('hide');
    }
});
```